# I can't install an add-on (plugin)

Tags: python

I have a problem with installing an add-on [Boolean Collections Plugin](https://pastebin.com/umxZZ34T)

and problem is this[image]

How i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Installation**

The addon installed fine for me, no idea why you are getting that error message.

Firstly I copied the code from link provided pasted into and ran from  text editor, to test,  no issues.

[image]

Then I saved the file as `blender_collections.py` into my Desktop folder, hit install addon, chose the file, once again no issue

[image]

Thought how are you getting that error message, then it twigged, if you hit the download button the file is saved as `blender_2.8_boolean_collections_plugin_by_ispheria.py` and there is your issue.

The file name has more than one period "." in it. This is the issue.  Only have one period in the file name before the py extension.  Python uses the dot to separate modules, and objects contained therein, eg `bpy.props` where both are modules.

Recommend you rename the file to `boolean_collections.py` and it will install.

**Note**

Always pays to check the homepage of the addon. In this case on blender artists forum.  [The same issue has been raised.](https://blenderartists.org/t/2-8-boolean-collections-plugin/1136189/21?u=batfinger)

Comment: Thanks friend for the detailed answer, will try to do