# Module Installed, Add-On Missing

Tags: add-on

I've used both the **Install Add-on From File** method with the .zip and extracted folder and manually copied the extracted folder into the blender add-on folder, but regardless, the add-on does not appear amongst the rest; although the information tab appears in the upper right-hand corner saying the module is installed, again, nothing.

I'm using Blender 2.79 with io_scene_owm-blender-2.79; oddly enough beforehand I unknowingly installed the 2.77 version which *did* successfully appear but was obviously the incorrect version.

Comment: Have you removed the 2.77 version prior to installing the correct version?

Comment: Have answered this or similar  before, will search... but basically you cannot have a period "." in a module name.  Rename folder to  eg `io_scene_owm`

Comment: I did prior, yes.

Comment: Oh, that appeared to do the trick, thank you batFINGER!

Comment: (Found it) Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129606/i-cant-install-an-add-on-plugin