# Issue with installing an addon

Tags: add-on

i tried installing lip sync importer following the normal step of installing addons in blender but i keep getting this message [Modules Installed() from 'C:\users\tstick\Download\Compressed\io_import_lipSync-Blender2.8-master.zip'into 'C:\users\tstick\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.90\scripts\addons'] please what does this mean... What i'm I not getting right?

Comment: what's wrong? this message looks like it installed normaly

Comment: Same as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129606/i-cant-install-an-add-on-plugin   rename the zip file to `io_import_lipSync.zip` If the installer tries to use the zip file name stem as the module name it will not import as a module because it has a period in it.  See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install

Comment: I have tried it, still having the same problem